# iOS object dealloc but it's method was leaking?

Tags: memory, overflow

I use '[NSLog(@"%p init");' in **init** method. And use 'NSLog(@"%p dealloc")' in **dealloc** method.The object is exactly destroyed; 
Then I use the **Leaks** tool find that the object is destroyed but it's method's memory is leaking.

Answer (score 0):

I has found the reason.Because inside the method I call the c **malloc** function.